# Can't get value from object key using .notation or bracket notation

Tags: object, notation

```
for(j=0;j<twitchUserArray.length;j++)
        {
          displayALL(twitchUserArray[j]);
        }

    function displayALL(person){
      console.log("Inside displayALL");
      console.log(person);
      console.log(person.logo);

     }
```

Array[9]

0: Object

```
game: ""
logo: "http: //static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/freecodecamp-profile_image-f1b681380c0b0380-300x300 .png"
name: "freecodecamp"
status: null
twitchfeed: "http: //www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp"
__proto__: Object
```

1: Object

```
game: ""
logo: "http: //static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/storbeck-profile_image-7ab13c2f781b601d-300x300 .jpeg"
name: "storbeck"
status: null
twitchfeed: "http: //www.twitch.tv/storbeck"
__proto__: Object
```

2: Object

```
game: ""
logo: null
name: "terakilobyte"
status: null
twitchfeed: "http: //www.twitch.tv/terakilobyte"
__proto__: Object
```

Can anyone tell me the right syntax to get the values of a key when inside my displayALL function. Each index in that for loop is an object. Console.log(person) shows me the object with all the keys and values when troubleshooting in chrome but I've tried . notation and bracket notation and cannot get anything but undefined

Comment: http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/VeaKYm

This is the codepen if you'd prefer to look at that. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show us what's in that array.

Comment: OK, added the first three of the array. Showing each one as a separate index and what is in it. All 9 have all the same keys. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should look to see what a person is using typeof in displayALL

```
   for(j=0;j<twitchUserArray.length;j++)
    {
      displayALL(twitchUserArray[j]);
    }

    function displayALL(person){
      console.log("Inside displayALL");
      console.log(person);
      console.log(typeof person);
 }
```

Comment: console.log(typeof person);

logs object to me. which is why I'm not sure why I can't use dot notation to get the values. Did you get something different?

Comment: I've done some further console.log testing and the function displayALL is not the issue. for some reason console.log(twitchUserArray) gives me the array of objects like I'd expect. But then if I try to run a that for loop or even just a for loop that console.log(twitchUserArray[j]) it logs to the console empty objects. So I don't know why all the data in the objects is disappearing.

Comment: Yes, your problem is with callbacks and such. You need to pay attention to what happens with your Ajax call.